# Vehicle Spawning Menu looping infinitely in lua

Tags: lua, scripting, menu, fivem

```
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do 
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        local playerPed = GetPlayerPed()
        local rank = exports.XpM:XPM_GetRank() --Gets the rank of the player from XP system XpM
print('Rank:' .. rank)
        if rank>50 then
          EighthItem(mainMenu) --All the different menu available for the player to choose vehicles from
          FifthItem(mainMenu)
          SixthItem(mainMenu)
          ThirdItem(mainMenu)
          ForuthItem(mainMenu)
          SeventhItem(mainMenu)
          FirstItem(mainMenu)
          SecondItem(mainMenu)
        elseif rank>40 then
          FifthItem(mainMenu)
          SixthItem(mainMenu)
          ThirdItem(mainMenu)
          ForuthItem(mainMenu)
          SeventhItem(mainMenu)
          FirstItem(mainMenu)
          SecondItem(mainMenu)
        elseif rank>30 then
          SixthItem(mainMenu)
          ThirdItem(mainMenu)
          ForuthItem(mainMenu)
          SeventhItem(mainMenu)
          FirstItem(mainMenu)
          SecondItem(mainMenu)
        elseif rank>20 then
          ThirdItem(mainMenu)
          ForuthItem(mainMenu)
          SeventhItem(mainMenu)
          FirstItem(mainMenu)
          SecondItem(mainMenu)
        else
          ForuthItem(mainMenu)
          SeventhItem(mainMenu)
          FirstItem(mainMenu)
          SecondItem(mainMenu)
        end
       _menuPool:RefreshIndex()
    end
end)
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do   --
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        _menuPool:ProcessMenus()
        if not IsPedInAnyVehicle(PlayerPedId()) and IsControlJustPressed(1, 243) then  --Console
            mainMenu:Visible(not mainMenu:Visible())
        elseif IsPedInAnyVehicle(PlayerPedId()) and IsControlJustPressed(1, 243) then  --Console
            exports['mythic_notify']:SendAlert('error', 'Player is in Vehicle')
        end
    end
end)
```

This code is used to spawn vehicles via a menu but the menu is looping infinite time when the code is run. The rank parameter is used to open specific vehicle categories for people with a certain level. The rank of the player is linked with an XP system script and retrieved to check the rank before opening the menu and provide the available categories accordingly

Comment: you're running an infinite while loop `while true do` ... what is your actual question?

Comment: I was unaware that `while true do` was an infinite loop, how do I fix this? I don't it to run an infinite loop, its looping the menu infinitely

Comment: I suggest you learn a few Lua basics befor you continue with this code. if you don't know Lua's basic control structures like while loops you cannot make sense of complex code nor fix any errors.

Comment: Alright I will, although I solved the issue with this one using multiple if loops

Comment: "if loops" do not exist

Answer (score 0):

Just make a boolean variable that defines if the loop was already ran.

Example:

```
local LoopRan = false
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
 while true do
  while LoopRan == false do
   -- Do things
   LoopRan = true
   Citizen.Wait(1337)
  end
 end
end)
```